# Django Rest Framework Pagination Overriding

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I think I am establishing a global pagination setting and overriding it in a base viewset, but that does not seem to be happening.

In my settings, I have:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10
}
```

but on my viewset I have

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    """ DRF endpoint. """

    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    paginate_by = None  # Note this guy right here
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    lookup_field = 'my_id'
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name',)
```

When I hit the endpoint, I get pagination by 10s.  Is this not the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `None` as the value has the same effect as not setting the `paginate_by` attribute at all. Have a look at [the code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L265) of DRF. You'll have to set an explicit value there for it to have effect.

As long as we're on the topic, though, the `'PAGINATE_BY'` global setting [will soon be deprecated](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.1-announcement/#pagination) in favor of `'PAGE_SIZE'`, and the per-view `paginate_by` class attribute should be replaced with a [custom paginator subclass](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style).